# Java quick instantiation

Tags: java, iterator, instantiation

How would I instantiate DictionaryADT dictionary in the constructor in this code? Also, If someone could help with the Iterators that would be cool. Lastly, if you could help with the print functions that would be nice.

```
import data_structures.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ProductLookup {


DictionaryADT<String,StockItem> dictionary;
private int maxSize;

// Constructor.  There is no argument-less constructor, or default size
public ProductLookup(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

// Adds a new StockItem to the dictionary
public void addItem(String SKU, StockItem item) {
    dictionary.insert(SKU,item);
}

// Returns the StockItem associated with the given SKU, if it is
// in the ProductLookup, null if it is not.
public StockItem getItem(String SKU) {
    if (SKU == null)
        return null;
    return dictionary.getValue(SKU);
}

// Returns the retail price associated with the given SKU value.
// -.01 if the item is not in the dictionary
public float getRetail(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return (float) -.01;
    return getItem(SKU).getRetail();
}

public float getCost(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return (float) -.01;
    return getItem(SKU).getCost();
}

// Returns the description of the item, null if not in the dictionary.
public String getDescription(String SKU) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(SKU))
        return null;
    return getItem(SKU).getDescription();
}

// Deletes the StockItem associated with the SKU if it is
// in the ProductLookup.  Returns true if it was found and
// deleted, otherwise false.  
public boolean deleteItem(String SKU) {
    if (SKU == null)
        return false;
    return dictionary.remove(SKU);
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems with their associated
// price, in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void printAll() {
    Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
}

// Prints a directory of all StockItems from the given vendor, 
// in sorted order (ordered by SKU).
public void print(String vendor) {
    Iterator<StockItem> iterator = values();
    if (dictionary.getItem(SKU).getVendor() == vendor)
        System.out.println(tmp.toString());
}

// An iterator of the SKU keys.
public Iterator<String> keys() {
    return new ;

}

// An iterator of the StockItem values.    
public Iterator<StockItem> values() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it be any different than then way you have done maxSize?

```
public ProductLookup(int maxSize, DictionaryADT<String,StockItem> dictionary) {
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
    this(maxSize);
}

// Constructor.  There is no argument-less constructor, or default size
public ProductLookup(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}
```

Comment: Yeah would like to do that, but I can't change the function for these class so it has to be public ProductLookup(int maxSize)

Comment: @FlameArc Why can't you change the constructor, out of curiosity?

Comment: That is just how the assignment is written

Comment: Write this new constructor and call **this(maxSize)** from it?

Comment: I don't understand that would this class be private and call maxSize from the public one above?

Comment: See the edited core. You are not changing the existing constructor.

Comment: That works you just have to have this(maxSize) above this.dictionary = dictionary